# SPARQL Query filter values from another resource

Tags: sparql

I have a query made like this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX sw: <http://www.semanticweb.org/lorep/ontologies/2021/7/untitled-ontology-3#>
SELECT  ?Name ?Surname ?Birth ?y
WHERE { 
?x sw:is_in ?y ;
sw:Name ?Name;
sw:Surname ?Cognome;
sw:Birth ?Birth;
}
```

Is there any way to filter from a specific value of the resource y?
I'm quite new to query so any help would be appreciated

Comment: did you try to use a `FILTER` expression?

Comment: Yes I tried but it does return an empty list, maybe because I don't know hot to use filter in y because it's a class and not an attribute. I tried `FILTER(y="dog")` (dog is just an example) but it does not work

Comment: yeah, that's wrong indeed. classes are identified by URIs, thus you have to use `FILTER(y=sw:dog)` or whatever the URI of the class is. Not that I understand why you have this weird property `sw:is_in` when RDF itself has its own relation to assign an individual to a class, called `rdf:type`

Comment: Yeah I know, all the SPARQL theory has been explained by our professor in one hour, obviosly I don't have it clear in my mind. Maybe I explained myself badly but `is_in` is an object property and `x` and `y` are classes. I don't know why but `sw` is the only way for me to visualize some result.

Comment: Nevermind solved with the `y=sw:dog`, thanks!